# I shred files under /, and now I get kernel panic, what can I do?

Tags: boot, kernel

I accidentally deleted all files under `/`, my system doesn't start anymore. Folders and links still there, nothing seems to be lost. but *"kernel panic not syncing unable to mount root fs"* after grub tried to start the system.

Fully encrypted xubuntu 12.04 system, encryption alright, accessible using rescue. Tried several things with rescue and installed a new system on other partition to copy deleted files manually. but no additional files there. Maybe files which only occur on an encrypted system?

- I need a way to repair my system (missing files?)
- And a way to boot it again, since I had to install grub in the MBR for the system on the other partition (didn't work another way, installation/rescue/ubuntu became ridiculous).

Comment: How have you deleted those files? Do you know which ones you deleted?

Comment: Easiest way is to reinstall from scratch, then restore your backups. Really, you should never delete `/` recursively. And if this is urgent, Ask Ubuntu (a Q&A site) is not the right place. Hire an expert instead.

Comment: using shred * PATH instead shred PATH *. since shred can't delete links or folders it shouldn't be a problem. but directly after the next reboot a kernel panic occured and it's not booting.

Comment: don't have an expert to hire. try to avoid reinstallation. took over a week last time, xubuntu tricky and need safe config. reinstallation would also cause data loss, because xubuntu can't access encrypted /home from outside.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, if what you say in comments is correct you used `shred *` with the root user (the only way you could do this). But first, lets read the manual:

> DESCRIPTION:
>          Overwrite  the specified FILE(s) repeatedly, in order to make it harder
>          for even very expensive hardware probing to recover the data.

So, what you did. You simply replaced the contents of the files (not the files itself) with garbage:

```
braiam@bt:~/lab$ touch file1 file2 file3
braiam@bt:~/lab$ ls
file1  file2  file3
braiam@bt:~/lab$ cat *
braiam@bt:~/lab$ 
braiam@bt:~/lab$ shred *
braiam@bt:~/lab$ cat *
VXK��6z�z�-K� Eˎ�F��O�č��ؖɄw����Pw(R�����xd/���O��2����lD�y�0��8Gй�4Q�k�7��ݤ
## Actually there was more garbage here, but it would make this answer too long.
```

Yeah, the last line is the "content" of the once empty files. That's why when you check the files, they are still there, but the content is all a mess.

Luckily, shred can't open directories:

```
braiam@bt:~/lab$ mkdir dir
braiam@bt:~/lab$ mkdir dir1
braiam@bt:~/lab$ mkdir dir2
braiam@bt:~/lab$ ls 
dir  dir1  dir2  file1  file2  file3
braiam@bt:~/lab$ touch dir/file2
braiam@bt:~/lab$ touch dir1/file2
braiam@bt:~/lab$ touch dir2/file2
braiam@bt:~/lab$ shred *
shred: dir: failed to open for writing: Is a directory
shred: dir1: failed to open for writing: Is a directory
shred: dir2: failed to open for writing: Is a directory
braiam@bt:~/lab$ cat dir/file2 
braiam@bt:~/lab$
```

So, everything that was below `/*/` are safe. That leaves us with the question, *what exactly then you messed up?*

```
$ ls -p / | grep -v /
0
initrd.img
vmlinuz
```

<sub>(I really don't know  what is doing that file named 0 there, but lets ignore him)</sub>

So you messed up the `initrd.img` that in my case links to `initrd.img -> /boot/initrd.img-3.10-1-686-pae` and the `vmlinuz` that in my case link to `vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.10-1-686-pae`. A `dpkg -S` will tell us what packages has those files:

```
$ dpkg -S boot/vmlinuz-3.10-1-686-pae
linux-image-3.10-1-686-pae: /boot/vmlinuz-3.10-1-686-pae
$ dpkg -S initrd.img-3.10-1-686-pae
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *initrd.img-3.10-1-686-pae*
```

As you can see, the vmlinuz* file is inside the `linux-image-3.10-1-686-pae`, so a simple reinstallation in a chrooted environment should be enoght. For the initrd.img things are tricky, and will need the use of `mkinitramfs` or more specifically `update-initramfs`:

```
$ update-initramfs -h
Usage: /usr/sbin/update-initramfs [OPTION]...

Options:
 -k [version]   Specify kernel version or 'all'
 -c     Create a new initramfs
 -u     Update an existing initramfs
 -d     Remove an existing initramfs
 -t     Take over a custom initramfs with this one
 -b     Set alternate boot directory
 -v     Be verbose
 -h     This message
```

With calling `update-initramfs` in the chrooted enviroment is likely that you will get your system up again.

Comment: With` ls -l` I can see `initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-112-lowlatency`. These files are links to the files in the `/boot`-folder, just recreating the links should be enough?

Comment: @mook765 no, the links aren't the problem. shred modified the underlying files those link pointed to.

Comment: Oh yes, I see that now, shred overwrote the files the links pointed to. Good to know, I never used shred so far but I am warned now... Thanks!